# Python Hangman not ending when player guesses all letters

Tags: python

My problem is that when I run the program and get all the letters correct, it does not move on from there and I'm in an infinite loop. I expect it to say "Good Job!" and end the program when the player gets the word right. I am very new to coding, and would greatly appreciate any help.

```
import random
import time

name = input("What is your name? ")
print(name + ", ay?")
time.sleep(1)
start = input("Up for a game of Hangman?(y/n) ")

lis = random.choice(["yet"])
dash = []
while len(dash) != len(lis):
   dash.append("_") 
guess = []
guesscomb = "".join(guess)
wrongcount=int(0)
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

if start == "y":
    print("One game of Hangman comin' right up,",name)
    letter = input("Alright then, Guess a letter: ")
    thing = ''.join(dash)

    while guesscomb != thing:
        if letter == "" or letter == " " or len(letter) != 1:
            print("I don't understand. Please only use singular letters.")
            letter = input("Guess a letter: ")    

        elif letter in lis and letter in alphabet:
            print("Nice!")

            location = lis.find(letter)
            dash[location] = letter
            guess.append(letter)
            alphabet.replace(letter," ")
            guesscomb = "".join(guess)

            letter = input("Guess a letter: ")

        else:
            print("Wrong.")
            wrongcount = wrongcount + 1

            print("Total Mistakes:",wrongcount)
            letter = input("Guess a letter: ")      

elif start == "n":
    input("Shame.")
    quit()

print("Good Job!")
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `thing` variable is equal to `___` while `lis` is always equal to `"yet"`.

`guesscomb` cannot be equal to `thing` as you validate a letter when the guess is equal to a letter in `lis`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print` with the parameter `end=""` so that the cursor don't go new line.
You can use the method `isalpha` on string to check if it is all characters instead of comparing it with the alphabets.
And as Ben said, `thing` is always ___

Modify this part of your code, and it will work

```
if start == "y":
    print("One game of Hangman comin' right up,", name)
    print("Alright then, ", end="")
    # letter = input("Alright then, Guess a letter: ")
    thing = ''.join(dash)

    while guesscomb != thing:
        letter = input("Guess a letter: ")
        if letter == "" or letter == " " or len(letter) != 1:
            print("I don't understand. Please only use singular letters.")

        elif letter in lis and letter in alphabet:
            print("Nice!")
            location = lis.find(letter)
            dash[location] = letter
            guess.append(letter)
            alphabet.replace(letter, " ")
            guesscomb = "".join(guess)
        else:
            print("Wrong.")
            wrongcount = wrongcount + 1
            print("Total Mistakes:", wrongcount)
        thing = ''.join(dash)
```